# postgresql - removing duplicates

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have 4 tables that i did a UNION with and the total count is roughly about 13 mils for an service_id field and 790k for a distinct service_id field.

| cust_id | service_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0423 |
| 2 | 0456 |
| 3 | 0423 |

When i did a count using

```
SELECT COUNT(service_id) as full_count, service_id
 FROM temp
 GROUP BY service_id
 HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
```

I got service_id 0423 x 2

However, when i did

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as full_count, COUNT(DISTINCT cust_id) as dist_cust_id
FROM temp
```

I got the result of

| full_count | dist_cust_id |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 3 |

My question is then how do i remove duplicate service_id and keeping 1 and knowing the one i keep is a valid one. Some tables do have a last_update column and some don't which adding to the complexity.

I have tried doing the SELF JOIN of the same table where a.cust_id <> b.cust_id AND a.service_id = b.service_id to identify which service_id has two or more cust_id. Not sure how I can keep the right one.

Thanks

Comment: It is Redshift that I am using.

Comment: You cannot solve this problem without coming up with a rule to determine which row you want to keep. There's not magic SQL that's going to figure that out for you.

Comment: @DaniU Thank you. I know there isn't an easy way hence i reached out to experts on here to gain ideas on how they normally solve this issue.